# Symfony: Use stylesheet with PdfBundle

Tags: php, symfony, pdf-generation

In an implementation of [PdfBundle](http://knpbundles.com/psliwa/PdfBundle), adding a stylesheet to the Pdf() annotation neither throws an error or is used.  The page rendered is a default 8.5 x 11, not the expected 5 x 8.  Replacing the stylesheet file name with random characters does not elicit an error.  Is other configuration required to take advantage of a stylesheet?

#### Controller:

```
   /**
     * @Pdf(stylesheet="ManaClientBundle:Test:pdfstyle.xml.twig",
     * @Route("/card")
     */
    public function cardAction() {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $household = $em->getRepository('ManaClientBundle:Household')->find(8607);
        $facade = $this->get('ps_pdf.facade');
        $response = new Response();
        $this->render('ManaClientBundle:Test:card.pdf.twig', array(
            'household' => $household,
            'date' => date_create(),
        ), $response);
        $xml = $response->getContent();
        $content = $facade->render($xml);
        return new Response($content, 200, array('content-type' => 'application/pdf'));
    }
```

#### Template (in .../Resources/views/Test/)

```
<pdf>
    <page id="card">
    ...
    </page>
</pdf>
```

#### Stylesheet in .../Resources/views/Test/pdfstyle.xml.twig

```
<stylesheet>
    <page id="card" page-size="8in:5in"  margin=".5in" font-size="12">
    </page>
</stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the author of the bundle:

If you use $facade object directly, Pdf annotation is unnecessary. You should use Pdf annotation when you want to use pdf rendering in implicit way. In you code you should pass stylesheet xml as second argument of $facade->render(...) method.

Controller now reads:

```
   /**
     * @Route("/card")
     */
    public function cardAction() {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $household = $em->getRepository('ManaClientBundle:Household')->find(8607);

        $stylesheetXml = $this->renderView('ManaClientBundle:Test:pdfstyle.xml.twig', array());

        $facade = $this->get('ps_pdf.facade');
        $response = new Response();

        $this->render('ManaClientBundle:Test:card.pdf.twig', array(
            'household' => $household,
            'date' => date_create(),
        ), $response);
        $xml = $response->getContent();
        $content = $facade->render($xml, $stylesheetXml);
        return new Response($content, 200, array('content-type' => 'application/pdf'));
    }
```